# Using ML.NET I would like to detect anomalies in DataStage ETL job runs

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net, datastage, anomaly-detection

I would like to detect the anomalies of the ETL job runs which processes the same amount of rows (either produced or consumed) but it takes longer to do it (based on the `ElapsedRunSecs` property).

The input schema looks like this:

```
public class JobRun
{

    public float ElapsedRunSecs { get; set; }
    public float TotalRowsConsumed { get; set; }

    public float TotalRowsProduced { get; set; }
    public DateTime RunStartTimestamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime RunEndTimestamp { get; set; }

}
```

I got to the point to establish the database connection, load the data and train the test split data:

```
        var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Oracle");
        var sqlCommand =
            "SELECT ELAPSEDRUNSECS, TOTALROWSCONSUMED, TOTALROWSPRODUCED, RunStartTimestamp, RunEndTimestamp from DSODB.JOBRUN";
        var dbSource = new DatabaseSource(new OracleClientFactory(), connectionString, sqlCommand);
        var mlContext = new MLContext();
        var databaseLoader = mlContext.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader<JobRun>();
        var dataView = databaseLoader.Load(dbSource);
        var testTrainSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(dataView, testFraction: 0.2);
```

I am not sure what the next steps should be.

Comment: Couldn't you answer your question ("which jobs are taking too long?") just with a query?

Comment: My apologies if you're doing this as an exercise in ML rather than as a production app!

Comment: Is not about which jobs is taking too long, but rather finding when the same job behaves differently in a time interval when processing similar amount of data.

Comment: I don't recommend trying to reinvent the wheel, because there are already tools out there which are capable of doing so.

Extract jobrun information from DSODB and feed it to a professional application performance monitoring tool like DataDog, Splunk, AppDynamics, or others. These tools are already able to detect and show unusual deviations. Be aware that in my opinion, this needs an analyst professional who is firm in configuring and interpreting such a tool.